# mediaelement.js failing when loaded via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, mediaelement.js

I have a simple page which uses the mediaelement.js audioplayer plugin.  The player attaches and functions correctly when loaded normally. However, when the page is loaded via ajax, the mediaelementplayer does not attach to the audio tag.
I use this code to call the file via ajax and jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="/test-vocabulary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".ajax_vocab_link").click(function(evento){
     evento.preventDefault();
     var ajaxDivNum = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
      var searchTerm = $(this).attr('title');
      $("#ajaxcontainer_"+ajaxDivNum).load("test-audioplayer-se.php", {chrisSearch: searchTerm}
      );
   });

})
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p><button class='ajax_vocab_link' id='ajaxlink_1' title='clothes'>Link to load ajax doc</button></p>
<div class='ajax_vocab_container' id='ajaxcontainer_1'>This is div id ajaxcontainer_1</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The audioplayer page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Audio Player CSS & Scripts -->

    <script src="http://www.ingles23.com/audioplayer/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ingles23.com/audioplayer/css/style4.css" media="screen">

    <!-- end Audio Player CSS & Scripts -->

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                      $('#audio-player-vocab0').mediaelementplayer({
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                features: ['playpause'],
                audioVolume: 'horizontal',
                audioWidth: 400,
                audioHeight: 120
            });


    });
    </script>



</head>
<body>



<div class='display_vocab_container' >
<div class='display_vocab_text' >
<div class='audio-player-slim'>
<audio controls='controls' type='audio/mp3' src='/sound/mp3/i23-crear-frases-ingles-5.mp3' id='audio-player-vocab0'></audio>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I've tried many combinations including using on, live, success and moving the css/js links between the documents, but these have all made the situation worse.
What can i do get the file to attach medaielementplayer when loaded via ajax?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891421/wordpress-audio-player-not-loading-when-the-content-is-loaded-through-ajax-medi

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the mediaelementplayer() function call in the ajax success function, that worked for me. So unless you want to use .ajax instead of .load you'll need to pass it as the second argument to the load function. Or use http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

```
$(".ajax_vocab_link").click(function(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    var ajaxDivNum = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    var searchTerm = $(this).attr('title');
    $("#ajaxcontainer_"+ajaxDivNum).load("test-audioplayer-se.php", function() {
        $('#audio-player-vocab0').mediaelementplayer({
            alwaysShowControls: true,
            features: ['playpause'],
            audioVolume: 'horizontal',
            audioWidth: 400,
            audioHeight: 120
        });
    });
});
```