# WORDPRESS Audio Player not loading when the content is loaded through Ajax, MediaElement.js no applied

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress theme. 
When I load the content using ajax it doesn't apply MediaElements.js to my audio player, so the audio isn't display. I think this is because the MediaElement.js is loaded with wp-footer(), and this new audio is added to the DOM after, and it's not recognized for MediaElement.js.

The same happend with local videos.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I was elated to see your question!  I was searching for help on a small problem, but this is essentially the precise overall problem I'm trying to solve.  Thanks for asking this question, and thanks to the answers below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reinstantiate the `MediaElement` object on your newly appended elements.

```
success: function(response){
    $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an `Observer` to watch and apply.

Comment: jQuery('video, audio').mediaelementplayer({
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                features: ['playpause'],
                audioVolume: 'horizontal',
                audioWidth: 400,
                audioHeight: 120
            });

Comment: I enqueue my script like this: wp_enqueue_script('lateral', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lateral-ajax.js', array('jquery', 'wp-mediaelement'), true);

Comment: YEA THAT WORKS!!! I have to enque the styles to wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' ); and     jQuery('video, audio').mediaelementplayer({
                                alwaysShowControls: true
                               
                            });

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this solves most cases:

You first need to make sure the mediaelement.js scripts are being loaded on all pages (ie even the ones that don't contain media).

functions.php (or similar)

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}, 100);
```

Then it should simply be a case of calling this in your JS once your AJAX content has been injected to the page

main.js (or wherever)

```js
$( window.wp.mediaelement.initialize );
```